# For how many application on IIS we can use the same MachineKey without loadbalancer?

Tags: asp.net, iis, viewstate

We have used same machine key without loadbalancer. Our applications are working fine. But we increased the number of websites on the IIS with same machine key.

Now we are getting the Viewstate error.

Error: **Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by Web FArm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm.**

Is there a limit in number of applications having same machine key on the IIS ?

Application is of .net framework 4.7.2

Comment: There is no limit for applications. However, you need to know why applications use machinekey. This error is that the applications in IIS are not well isolated. If you want to isolate your application from other applications on the same server, place the in the Web.config file for each application on each server in the farm. Ensure that you use separate key values for each application

Comment: If the keys are same then will the two applications will cause issue to each other ?

Comment: Also, what will happen in case application is using the same machine key. I mean what issue will occur. And what should I interpret from the error message above.

Comment: Some requests which contains user data or important information may send to another application or server who has the same machinekey.